# De-annex directory managed by `git-annex`

Tags: git, symlink, git-annex

There is an [open source dataset](https://gin.g-node.org/NeuralEnsemble/ephy_testing_data) that, if cloned, provides `git-annex`-managed symlinks. If I unlock the directory, I see files whose content has been replaced with hashes. For example, instead of the contents I see when accessing [settings.xml](https://gin.g-node.org/NeuralEnsemble/ephy_testing_data/src/master/openephysbinary/v0.4.4.1_with_spikes/settings.xml) via browser, I see `/annex/objects/MD5E-s208144--34d01773c20e00c210e1add9ccc1c87c.xml`.

How do I fully de-annex this dataset? My goal is to get the original file organization so my other scripts can read the content. My shell has trouble following system links to perform a recursive copy.

Comment: You'll need to install git-annex (well, you might not *need* to, but that's by far the easiest way to handle this). I updated the [tag:git-annex] tag wiki with a link to the main site, where you can find installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the documentation more thoroughly, I did the following...

1. Install `git-annex` - [link](https://git-annex.branchable.com/install/)
2. For relevant subdirectories, run `git-annex get <subdir>/*`
3. For relevant subdirectories, run `git-annex unlock <subdir>/*`